# Set sqlite pragma encoding to "UTF-16" in .net

Tags: c#, vb.net, sqlite, pragma

i want to set the encoding of SQLite to UTF-16. how can i do that from code?
prefferably in vb.net, but i am able to convert c# to vb.net

i use the database helper class from this url that i converted to vb.net code:
http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/ASP/How-to-use-SQLite-database-in-Visual-Studio.aspx

i tried this vb.net code:

```
      dbConnection = "Data Source=database.s3db;PRAGMA encoding = ""UTF-16"";"
```

but this diddent work.
after @Dai post i tried this in the constructor of the SQLiteDatabase helper class and deleted the old database

vb.net code:

```
    dbConnection = "Data Source=database.s3db;"
    Dim cnn As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbConnection)
    cnn.Open()
    Using cmd As SQLiteCommand = cnn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA encoding = ""UTF-16"";"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    cnn.Close()
```

c# code:

```
SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectioN)
c.Open()
using(SQLiteCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand()) {
cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA encoding = \"UTF-16\"";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
c.Close()
```

but this diddent work also, Administrator (The IDE of SQLite) still sad it was on UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite PRAGMA statements are evaluated as SQL commands, so not part of the connection string. This is documented on their website:

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html

> The PRAGMA statement is an SQL extension specific to SQLite and used to modify the operation of the SQLite library or to query the SQLite library for internal (non-table) data. **The PRAGMA statement is issued using the same interface as other SQLite commands (e.g. SELECT, INSERT)**

(emphasis mine)

So to set the encoding:

```
using(SQLiteCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA encoding = \"UTF-16\"";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question, i hope you would take a look at it?